# Java persistancemanager fetch return less entities

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, data-persistence

In java fetching entities with query some time return less entities in some rare case. I am using javapersistance manager. Is it ideal to use it or need to switch to low level datastore fetch to solve it?

```
String query = "CUID == '" + cuidKey + "' && staffKey == '" + staffKey +"'&& StartTimeLong >= "+ startDate + " && StartTimeLong < " + endDate + " && status == 'confirmed'";

List<ResultJDO> tempResultList = jdoUtils.fetchEntitiesByQueryWithRangeOrder(ResultJDO.class, query, null, null, "StartTimeLong desc");
```

The result returned 4 entities in rare case, but most time return all 5 entities.

jdoUtils is a PersistanceManager object. 
Should I need to switch to low level datastore fetch for exact results.

Comment: Please add more details to your problem. Add some code how you query your db.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried researching about the library you mentioned and for similar issues and found nothing that far. It's hard to know why this is happening or how to fix it with as little information.

On the other hand, the recommended way of programmatically interact with Google Cloud Platform products is through [Google's client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) since they are already tested and assured to work in almost all cases. Furthermore, their usage allows to open Github issue's if you find any problem so that the developers could address them. For the rare cases that you need some functionality not already covered you can open a feature request or directly call the API's.

In addition to Google's libraries there are two other options for Java that are under active development. One is [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify) and the other is [Catatumbo](https://github.com/sai-pullabhotla/catatumbo).

I would suggest switching to [Java Datastore libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java). You could find examples on how to interact with Datastore in [link1](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-basic-entity-java) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-datastore-basic-query-java). Also you could find community shared code samples in this [programcreek page](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService).